# Is there a better and optimized way to create a nested list with C#?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I want to create a flat list based on three Enumerable lists. The data of these list are stored in three tables in my DB : Continent, Country, City.
To do so, i fetch trough 3 loops for each Entity, so if i add another entity called District, i need a fourth loop and so on. So there's a way to optimize my code to use LooKup or a cleaner Linq Syntax and also improve the performance ? See my code below :

Continent

```
Id  Name            
1   NorthAmerica    
2   Europe
```

Country

```
Id  Name              ContinentId        
1   USA               1
2   CANADA            1
3   FRANCE            2
4   ENGLAND           2
```

Country

```
Id  Name              CountryId        
1   PARIS             3
2   MONTREAL          2
3   NEW YORK          1
4   LYON              3
5   LONDRES           4
```

In C#, i get the data for each table from a repository

```
var lists = new List<Select> { };

var continents = _unitOfWork.ContinentRepository.Get().
                 Select(x => new { id = x.Id, name = x.name });

var countries = _unitOfWork.CountryRepository.Get().
                Select(x => new { id = x.Id, continentId = x.ContinentId, name = x.name });

var cities = _unitOfWork.CityRepository.Get().
             Select(x => new { id = x.Id, countryId = x.CountryId, name = x.name });


if (continents.Count() > 0)
{
    foreach (var continent in continents)
    {
        lists.Add(new Select { Id = continent.id, Value = continent.name, Level = "first-level" });
        foreach (var country in countries.Where(x => x.continentId == continent.id))
        {
            lists.Add(new Select { Id =  country.id , Value = country.name, Level = "second-level" });
            foreach (var city in cities.Where(x => x.countryId == country.id))
            {
                lists.Add(new Select { Id = city.id , Value = city.name, Level = "third-level" });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
NORTHAMERICA
   USA 
     NEW YORK
   CANADA
     MONTREAL
EUROPE
  FRANCE
    LYON
    PARIS
  ...
```

```
The class attribute will add the spaces (indentation), so i need it.
[
    {
        "id": 1
        "value": "NorthAmerica",
        "class": "first-level"
    },
    {
        "id": 1
        "value": "USA",
        "class": "second-level"
    },
    {
        "id": 3
        "value": "NEW YORK",
        "class": "third-level"
    },
    {
        "id": 2
        "value": "CANADA",
        "class": "second-level"
    },
    {
        "id": 3
        "value": "MONTREAL",
        "class": "third-level"
    },
    {
        "id": 2
        "value": "Europe",
        "class": "first-level"
    },
    {
        "id": 1
        "value": "FRANCE",
        "class": "second-level"
    },
    {
        "id": 3
        "value": "PARIS",
        "class": "third-level"
    },
    {
        "id": 4
        "value": "LYON",
        "class": "third-level"
    },
    {
        "id": 4
        "value": "ENGLAND",
        "class": "second-level"
    },
        "id": 5
        "value": "LONDRES",
        "class": "third-level"
    },
]
```

Comment: are you using Entityframework as repository ?

Comment: Why do you want a flat list like this? A proper object graph would likely be much more useful or 3 lists if that is not an object as the user of the flat list would otherwise need to filter and/or group.

Comment: This is a very odd representation of that data. How are you going to consume it?  I'd have represented it as a hierarchy: `Continent->Country->City`. Something like: `[{NorthAmerica, [{Canada, [{Montreal}]}, USA, [{NewYork}]}},` etc. _(that's JSON edited in this little box, not necessarily correct JSON)_

Comment: Does list order matter?

Comment: It's the *repository's* job to return a proper object graph. I suspect you used the "generic repository" **anti**pattern on top of EF, preventing the ORM from loading related entities, so now you have to join the entities together again. With a proper design you shouldn't have to write anything other than `dbContetxt.Cities.Where(city=>city.Country.Continent.Name=="Europe").ToList()`  to get all cities in Europe along with their country and continent entities

Comment: The output is *flattened* which means an ORM won't offer anything over a SQL statement that returnes the flattened results. Even with an ORM, loading the graph doesn't need loops. No matter how you load it you'd have to *flatten* it though. You can't get from entities to the kind of result you want just like this

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you are doing something like that in those days where there is library that could handle this much better like 
EntityFramework and EntityWorker.Core

In Entityworker.Core this could easly be done with a single select 
here is an example of your modules

```
public class Continent {

  [PrimaryKey]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }

}

public class Country {

  [PrimaryKey]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  public string Name { get; set; }

  [ForeignKey(typeof(Continent))]
  public int ContinentId { get; set; }

  public List<City > Cities { get; set; }

}

   public class City {

      [PrimaryKey]
      public int Id { get; set; }

      public string Name { get; set; }


      [ForeignKey(typeof(Country))]
      public int CountryId { get; set; }
  }
```

now all you have to do is get the data and loadChildren

```
using (var rep = new Repository())
   {
     // this will load all Continent and Countries and Cities all togather with a single call
    List<Continent> Continents = rep.Get<Continent>().Where(x=> x.Id == 54).LoadChildren().Execute(); 
   }
```

here more information about the library 
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1222424/EntityWorker-Core-An-Alternative-to-Entity-Framewo

Entityframework can do the same thing except instead of LoadChildren you do Include()
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/basics/context-class-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: No reason to use `Include`. `dbContetxt.Cities.Where(city=>city.Country.Continent.Name=="Europe").ToList()` will load all cities in Europe

Comment: @Alen.Toma,  What is the benefit of linking an additional library to thier project.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos loading all of the data at the same time will cause cartesian production, Depending on performance constraints they might just want to load city countries and continents in seperate calls

Comment: @johnny5 why? If the relations are properly configured, EF should produce a single query that joins the three tables together by ID. That's the same thing one would do in SQL.

Comment: @Panagiotis yes but then your sending  duplicates for each city you contain its country and continent,  if your server is hosted else where your sending alot of extra data it might be more efficient to make 3 separate request to avoid the duplicates caused by the join

Comment: All your approaches make sens but it doesnt reproduce the output i want ! Hence i used the 3 differents loops so i can have a better flexibility. With your answers, i dont see the class attribute that will help  meto add the spaces i need for the display depending on the level

Comment: You should disclose that you are the author of that library.

Comment: @lory you haven't explained *what* you want. No matter how you load the city graph, it has to be transformed to something completely different to get the output you want.